# How can I encode/decode (HTTP request.get DATA) in Python

Tags: python

in python, I used HTTP

```py
requests.get(URL, params=params).
```

and, I got `res.text` like this...

```
{
"resno":"3330101",
"subj":"1211517",
"seltext":"%25EC%258B%25A4%25EB%25AC"
}
```

How can I encode/decode `%25EC%258B%25A4%25EB%25AC` ??

now, `res.encoding` is `"EUC-KR"`....

Comment: I want to get Korean Text like this "정말감사합니다."

Comment: I'm surprised `requests.get` didn't decode it automatically.